# Facebook Open Graph Not Working/Showing as a blank page

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I've been having some difficulty with sharing my site on social media - https://nobetterdan.com/.

When I do, it shows just the URL and nothing else.

Some background information:

Running:

WordPress 5.7.2

Soledad theme 7.9.3

Yoast Plugin - can't figure out how to find what version, but it should be the latest one

Things I've checked:

I've ran the social share debugger, which tells me the following messages:

```
Inferred Property

The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Missing Properties

The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
```

However, when I check the source of my site - view-source:https://nobetterdan.com/ - all of these are coming up:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Nobetterdan." />
<meta property="og:description" content="Life Advice From Someone Whose Life Is A Mess" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://nobetterdan.com/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="nobetterdan." />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://nobetterdan.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/nobetterdan-Facebook.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1640" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="856" />
```

So, it looks like the stuff is actually there.

Next step was to check what the scraper actually sees, so checked that and it just returned a blank page

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fnobetterdan.com%2F
```

Any ideas? Not sure where to go from here. It's probably something pretty easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

Figured it out.

It was because my SSL cert wasn't set up properly. If you're experiencing a similar problem, run whatever SSL check you can find and see if it finds any issues.